# Adding a column with averages in E list

Tags: arrays, r, bioinformatics

I am just getting my head around R and im performing microarray analysis using limma. I have picked up my Control ( CC) and Experiment ( EE) data.

I have ended up with an EList which has results of the Microarray intensities. 
Columns are CC-1, CC-2, CC-3 and EE-1, EE-2, EE-3,probe names and systematic names
I would like to add 2 columns which will be Average of CC 1-3 and Average of EE 1-3 but I am unsure of how to do it. Is there a simple way to do so?

I can do it in excel but I would really like to get familiar with R and use it fluently.

Comment: Since [limma](http://bioconductor.org/packages/limma) is a Bioconductor package, it's appropriate to ask questions on the Bioconductor [support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org)

Answer (score 1):

First I created a dataframe with some fake microarray signals values:

```
d = data.frame(abs(matrix(rnorm(30,mean=5),5,6)))
cc = c('CC-1', 'CC-2', 'CC-3')
ee = c('EE-1', 'EE-2', 'EE-3')
colnames(d) = c(cc,ee)
d 
      CC-1     CC-2     CC-3     EE-1     EE-2     EE-3
1 4.775333 4.702609 6.555690 4.853671 5.391154 6.252322
2 2.819228 4.899276 3.021709 4.474202 4.432656 4.576010
3 4.329981 5.689807 4.417229 5.444785 2.603174 3.207310
4 4.657848 4.840904 5.955579 6.359203 5.093865 5.255560
5 5.631977 5.043603 5.777581 3.985867 2.387029 5.115502
```

Then use `apply` to run a function that calculates the mean of the `cc` columns (and `ee` columns in the 2nd apply line) by row (the `1` argument). The vector of means for `cc` and `ee` are assigned as new columns to the data.frame.

```
d$ccm=apply(d, 1, FUN=function(x) { mean(x[cc]) } )
d$eem=apply(d, 1, FUN=function(x) { mean(x[ee]) } )
d

     CC-1     CC-2     CC-3     EE-1     EE-2     EE-3      ccm      eem
1 4.775333 4.702609 6.555690 4.853671 5.391154 6.252322 5.344544 5.499049
2 2.819228 4.899276 3.021709 4.474202 4.432656 4.576010 3.580071 4.494289
3 4.329981 5.689807 4.417229 5.444785 2.603174 3.207310 4.812339 3.751756
4 4.657848 4.840904 5.955579 6.359203 5.093865 5.255560 5.151444 5.569543
5 5.631977 5.043603 5.777581 3.985867 2.387029 5.115502 5.484387 3.829466
```